# MySQL Set row character set

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I want to set my row character set to UTF8 general or unicode (whatever I'd want ;-) )

**Have the following MySQL code :**

```
ALTER TABLE `pdo_test` CHANGE `pdo_text` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This however is wrong.

**The following would be correct:**

```
ALTER TABLE `pdo_test` CHANGE `pdo_text` `pdo_text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

However then I need to know many other sub info. Like the field type (VARCHAR(255), NULL etc etc)

Can't it simply be short like my desired example?

```
ALTER TABLE `pdo_test` CHANGE `pdo_text` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE `utf8_general_ci;`
```

Comment: What `CHARACTER SET` are the _columns_ currently?  Do you have data in the table _already_?  Is any of that data non-English?  _I ask these because there are different techniques needed for different cases._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE CHANGE has a clause **column_definition**
which refers to CREATE TABLE **column_definition**:

```
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
      [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
      [reference_definition]
  | data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
      [VIRTUAL | STORED] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [COMMENT comment]
      [NOT NULL | NULL] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
```

From this we can say that **data_type** is mandatory parameter. The query must be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `pdo_test` CHANGE `pdo_text` `pdo_text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci...
```

[CREATE TABLE Syntax.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Comment: Too bad it has to be like this. But thank you very much for your extensive explanation!

Comment: You could do it simply in GUI object editor, have a look at - [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Try free express edition.